# List available ffmpeg versions on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ffmpeg, apt-cache

Ubuntu 14.04 server here. I want to see what versions of `ffmpeg` are available for download. Usually I can run `apt-cache policy <packageName>` to do this, but because `ffmpeg` was excluded from the official Ubuntu repos as of 14.04, that command doesn't work.

I typically install `ffmpeg` with the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

But this doesn't give me control over which version gets installed.

So I ask: **On Ubuntu 14.04, how can I preview the list of available `ffmpeg` versions that are available, and then how do I specify any particular version?**

Please note: this is *not* the same as the answer for packages/libs that exist in the Ubuntu repos, because again, `ffmpeg` isn't in them.

Answer (score 1):

To list the available version you can you the following command.

```
apt-cache search ffmpeg | grep Version
```

To install a specific version, the syntax is as follows.

```
apt-get install ffmpeg=<version>
```

Where `<version>` should be replaced by the version string from the above command.

---

EDIT

If `apt-cache search ffmpeg | grep Version` does not report any version, it is very likely that you are missing a repository and you might want to add it.

```
add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
apt-get update
```

Comment: Thanks @Thomas (+1) but the first command yields the following error: `E: Invalid operation search`. Also I don't see how it could work because `ffmpeg` is not in the official Ubuntu repos (you have to add the `mc3man/trusty-media` repo manually first to make it available). Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks again @Thomas but `apt-cache search ffmpeg | grep Version` returns no results, likely because `apt-cache` cannot find `ffmpeg`, because `ffmpeg` is not the in the official Ubuntu repos.

Comment: Yes, `ffmpeg` is not in the official repository. As you mentioned the ppa above I thought you already know that...

Comment: Sure, thanks @Thomas, I think there might be a disconnect. It sounds like you are saying that I should be able to create a brand new Ubuntu 14.04 server and run `apt-cache search ffmpeg | grep Version`, and the output of that command should list all available versions. I'm seeing evidence that this is not true. Because when I create a brand new Ubuntu 14.04 server and run that command, there is no output whatsoever. Thoughts?

Comment: Ahh ok thanks @Thomas I see what the disconnect is. Yes, I have already added the `mc3man/trusty-media` repo using the exact same commands as what you put in your edit, and there is still **no output at all**. I should also note that I can verify `ffmpeg` is installed correctly. Perhaps the fact that I already have it installed is preventing your suggested command from generating any output?

Comment: Hi @Thomas (and everyone else reading this) - while I sincerely appreciate your help thus far, I simply can't mark this as an answer because your command doesn't actually produce any output for me.

Comment: I couldn't get any output either.

Answer (score 1):

See 'snap info ffmpeg' for additional versions.